# Probability With two sets being disjoint, exactly one of the events occur

Tags: statistics

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, with $P(A)=0.30$ and $P(B)=.6$. Find the probability that

(a)    At least one of the events occurs

$$P(A) \cup P(B)=.3+.6 $$

(b)   both of the events occur

$$P(A \cap B)=0 $$

(c) Neither events occurs
    .1

(d) exactly one of the events occur

Is this finding $P(A \cap B^c) \cup P(A^c \cap B)$??

I think it is .9 again since they dont occur at same time.

Comment: I think it means $P(A\cup B)=0.3+0.6$. Otherwise, $P(A)\cup P(B)$ what is it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your points **(a)** through **(c)** are (I believe) spot on $\ddot\smile$

Yes, **(d)** is asking you to calculate $P(A\cap B^c)\cup P(A^c\cap B)$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to (d) is correct. Here is a little more:

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).$

$P[(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)] = P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A\cap B).$

Comment: Maybe @Ugo wanted to work through this on his/her own. Maybe put the formula in a spoiler?